# JSP duplicate if included multiple time

Tags: java, jsp

let say i have this global.jsp that include a database configuration and connection.

I know this is not the best way to do this, and I didn't allow to use anything else then a pure jsp. The problem is when is this file is included in more than once then i got re-declaration error. Is there any way to do this ? something like IFDEF on C perhaps.

Thanks.

Comment: how about checking for not `null`? But still its not proper solution.

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to include any JSP more than once.

Comment: @HarryJoy: won't work due to `symbol not found` compile error if it isn't been declared before. Solution is just to design the templates more smart. But the OP probably already realized that.

Answer (score 1):

Check the jsp include concept here is the simple detail and difference of the include directive tag and include action tag

should use the include directive (`<%@ include file="relativeURL" %>`): 
if the file includes static text 
if the file is rarely changed (the JSP engine may not recompile the JSP if this type of included file is modified) 
if you have a common code snippet that you can reuse across multiple pages (e.g. headers and footers)

should use the `<jsp:include />`
for content that changes at runtime 
to select which content to render at runtime (because the page and src attributes can take runtime expressions) 
for files that change often

here are the links

1. http://javapapers.com/jsp/difference-between-jsp-include-directive-and-jsp-include-action/
2. http://www.geekinterview.com/question_details/701
3. http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/jsp/threads/105695

Comment: so basically i should use M%@ include %> so it does not compiled twice ?

Comment: and also database connection should be included once only so you can use into that page anywhere

Comment: That is the problem. how to handle if that file included twice by a mistake

Comment: directive always included on top so check for that

Comment: I see, but if latter, the application is so big and there is multiple file including other files. and it's not possible to check the file one by one. I want to prevent this.